# How to sync git repositories when central git repo (GitHub/BitBucket) is not available

Tags: git, github, ssh, bitbucket

Normally I push my git-changes from my development machine to BitBucket. This triggers a webhook to my other machine, which initiates a pull from BitBucket.

```
[my machine]
   \
    +---1.push--> [bitbucket] <---3.pull------+
                       \                       \
                        +--2.webhook--> [other machine]
```

However, it is possible for BitBucket to [not be available sometimes](https://status.bitbucket.org). So I also want to be able to push my changes to the other machine directly. My git protocol I use to sync with BitBucket is SSH, and I also have an SSH connection to my other machine.

So this is what I want to accomplish.

```
[my machine]
   \
    +---push--> [other machine]
```

The command to push I use is:

```
git push ssh://USERNAME@SSH_SERVER_NAME/path/to/remote/repository
```

When there's nothing to sync, I get the message `Everything up-to-date`. OK, nice. But when there is new commit to push, I get an error message (removed some lines for brevity).

```
! [remote rejected] master -> master (branch is currently checked out)
error: failed to push some refs to 'ssh://USERNAME@SSH_SERVER_NAME/path/to/remote/repository'
```

Someone suggested to switch branches, but I'm unsure if I'm doing the right thing here. Switching branches sound weird, because BitBucket doesn't switch branches either, so why should I do this?

The questions are:

1. How do I push a change, skipping my normal BitBucket workflow?
2. Can BitBucket catch up later with the changes? I a pull/push from both machines enough to restore the "normal" workflow?

Comment: I have an issue is with the term “central” repo as git is not a centralised vcs.

Answer (score 0):

You are pushing to a non bare repo, git issues this warning just to prevent a silent modification of the `master` branch on `[other machine]`, while someone is possibly working on it.

"Switch branch" means : go on `[other machine]`, and tell your live repo that you are not currently working on the `master` branch.

---

Here are some other ways to transmit the commit :

- go on `[other machine]` and *pull* from `[my machine]`
- create a bare repo on `[other machine]`, push from `[my machine]` to this bare repo, then on `[other machine]` pull locally from this bare repo